# .Net MAUI The 'run-as' command failed with 'run-as: Could not set capabilities: Operation not permitted

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I recently updated to MAUI Preview 6 with VS2022 Version 17.0.0 Preview 2.1 and my already working MAUI project started throwing the below error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       XA0137: The 'run-as command failed with 'run-as: Could not set capabilities: Operation not permitted
> '.
> Fast Deployment is not currently supported on this device.
> Please file an issue with the exact error message using the 'Help-> Send Feedback->Report a Problem' menu item in Visual Studio
> or 'Help-> Report a Problem' in Visual Studio for Mac.
> Please set the 'EmbedAssembliesIntoApk' MSBuild property to 'true' to disable Fast Deployment in the Visual Studio project property pages, or edit the project file in a text editor.

Is there something I am missing? Please let me know in case someone has a probable solution.

Also, I can see this issue even if I create a new project.

Also, I have performed a Maui-check and my installation seems to be proper.

Comment: You might find these debug tips useful, to clarify your question; https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/5794

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I know the reason for the issue the solution is what I seek.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a goodnight sleep I realised apparently, My answer was in my question itself!

Adding

```
 <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
```

To my MAUI projects property group solves this issue and I am able to run again.

I guess the issue was caused by Fast renderers not working with my current debug device which runs on Android 7

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Since it was indeed in your post I assumed you had seen it :) Although it is a workaround it technically isn't a solution but oh well, if it works for you I'm happy! :D

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Well, my only options were using the workaround or no debugging at all.

Comment: apparently, this is still an issue in the initial release of .NET Maui.

Comment: @WallaceB.McClure Actually this is not an issue with MAUI, but an issue with Fast renderers with Android versions below 8

Comment: @FreakyAli Whatever the error specifics are, adding this to the project file solved the problem.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are having more than 1 user-profile on your android phone/tablet. Then, please try removing all other profiles. This worked for my physical device.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Go to phone settings then apps and delete app for all users. It possible that you have uninstalled app from home screen but it is still there for other users going into settings and deleting it will resolved the issue.